# When more than one Shipping Rules applies, select the highest

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I am using Drupal 7 with Drupal Commerce to manage an eshop.
I have 8 product types and I manage the shipping per product type with price variations.
Product type 1 when price is lower than 50 euros has 5 euros shipping, product type 2 has 3 euros shipping when the price is lower than 30 euros etc
I manage doing that by adding rules after a product is placed at the cart , using 
"Price comparison" and "Order contains products of particular product types" conditions, and action "Apply shipping rate to an order".

It seems to work fine but when I add multiple products from various categories, the shipping rule that prevails is the rule applied to the first product added to the cart.
What I want is to compare all Shipping rules and keep the one with the highest cost.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please include an export of your rule related to what you wrote in "I manage doing that by adding". If we can see the rues logic you hae in place, it's much easier to pinpoint any issue (problem) with it, or to suggest an improved version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Total amount of selected products comparison in Commerce Order can be used for that condition.
A temporary solution is to apply the rule which only allows one product per cart.